# Trying to do an SOQL Query for all product names and their Price books

Tags: soql, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook, product, pricebookentry

I Have a Salesforce Org where there are almost 1000 products and 51 Price books, I want to know a query where I can get each product and the price books they belong to.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: You should definitely check out the wide range of tutorials in [Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Id, Name, Pricebook2.Id, Pricebook2.Name FROM Product2
```

but you should read up on SOQL in general because this is a rather basic question, you should be able to expand on this rather easily

Comment: Yeah im only recently a certified admin and am starting to learn about development tools. so im still pretty new to it all.